# How to fix this javascript onmousemove that is not working only on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, onmousemove

Im trying to create a ball that follow the cursor inside my site: www.effevisual.altervista.org using wordpress and divi theme.

I tried this code lot of times without any problem but actually it looks like the objects block the ball.

I also want if possible to change the ball to less opacity when the cursor is hover a link.

```
<body onload = "followMouse();">
<div class="wrap">
<div id="ball"></div>
</div></body>
```

```
.wrap {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
}

#ball {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     background: #0034fc;
     border-radius: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
 var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
 var $on = document.addEventListener.bind(document);

 var xmouse, ymouse;
 $on('mousemove', function (e) {
      xmouse = e.clientX || e.pageX;
      ymouse = e.clientY || e.pageY;
 });

 var ball = $('#ball');
 var x = void 0,
      y = void 0,
      dx = void 0,
      dy = void 0,
      tx = 0,
      ty = 0,
      key = -1;

 var followMouse = function followMouse() {
      key = requestAnimationFrame(followMouse);

      if(!x || !y) {
           x = xmouse;
           y = ymouse;
      } else {
           dx = (xmouse - x) * 0.125;
           dy = (ymouse - y) * 0.125;
           if(Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy) < 0.1) {
                x = xmouse;
                y = ymouse;
           } else {
                x += dx;
                y += dy;
           }
      }
      ball.style.left = x + 'px';
      ball.style.top = y + 'px';
 };

 </script>
```

Any message error, just the ball doesnt follow properly.

Comment: Okay, so two things, in order to change the opacity of the ball on hover, do the following: remove 'pointer-events: none;' from '#ball' as this seems to disable hover events, replace it with 'cursor: normal;' in '#ball'. Generally in your css file - add this:  #ball:hover { 
  opacity: 0.6; 
}

Answer (score 0):

So what I found is that you are applying a transform to the class `.et_pb_code_0`. `transform: translateX(-89px) translateY(-81px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(90deg);` That alone has sent your ball to a different direction making left and right up and down and up and down now left and right. 
Aside from that your wrapper and ball class are contained in many other divs which position it away from the top left of the page. 
I can fix it in inspecter by dragging the `wrap` class to the top under the `main-content1` class.

You will also have to apply `position:fixed` to the `wrap` class to keep it on the screen at all times. And a `z-index` for the lower parks of the page. And `pointer-events:none` so you can click links.

And something like this to get you started:

`jQuery( "li" ).mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery( "#ball" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
jQuery( "li" ).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery( "#ball" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 1, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});`

[image]

Comment: So, i solved the first issue. It was a really stupid error but after lot of hours coding i probably cloned the menu div and than changed the html so i got the transformation too. Thank you very much.

Anyway with thei jQuery the mouse ball fade to 100%, is possible to make less fade and maybe change the overlay mode to screen?